# Copying a unsigned char array using memcpy in C

Tags: c

```
int n=50;
unsigned char bytes[4];
unsigned char *buffer=(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(int));
bytes[0]=(n>>24)&0xFF;
bytes[1]=(n>>16)&0xFF;
bytes[2]=(n>>8)&0xFF;
bytes[3]=n&0xFF;

memcpy(buffer,bytes,sizeof(bytes));
```

This does not copy the bytes array to buffer. Any idea why?? What can be done to copy the array to buffer??

When I try to print the sizeof(buffer)  or the contents after memcpy it shows 0 and no contents.
I need to copy it to buffer as I have other information to append to the buffer along with bytes.

Comment: Where is `buffer` declared?

Comment: Please show a complete code example that demonstrates that the bytes have not been copied.

Comment: How is buffer defined? How are you determining that the buffer hasn't be copied into from bytes[]?. More code please.

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)`?  Show the evidence that "This does not copy the bytes array to buffer".

Comment: I have shown the complete code

Answer (score 1):

```
 int n=50;
```

Assuming that you are on a 32-bit machine, 'n' will be a 4-byte value.
n = 0x00000032 = 00000000b 00000000b 00000000b 00110010b

```
 unsigned char bytes[4];
```

bytes will ve a 4-byte value :

```
 bytes[0]=(n>>24)&0xFF;
```

byte[0] = 00000000b

```
 bytes[1]=(n>>16)&0xFF;
```

byte[1] = 00000000b

```
 bytes[2]=(n>>8)&0xFF;
```

byte[2] = 00000000b

```
 bytes[3]=n&0xFF;
```

byte[3] = 00110010b

```
memcpy(buffer,bytes,sizeof(bytes));
```

Copy (sizeof(bytes)) 4 bytes from bytes to buffer.

Whether or not this does what you expect is perhaps the question.
(More assumptions)

---

Assuming that buffer is:

```
int buffer[1];
```

the above statement would copy as expected.  However, if you test this assumption using code usch as:

```
printf("buffer = %d\n", buffer[0]);
```

The output will depend on what kind of machine you run it on; little endian, or bit endian.

On one, it will out put "buffer = 50"
On the other, it will output the decimal value which is equivelant to:

```
0x32000000 (00110010b 00000000 00000000b 00000000b 00000000b)
```

---

Assuming:

```
int buffer;
```

Will most likely generate a compiler warning (or error); and is probably not what you want, unless you change your memcpy() as follows:

```
memcpy(&buffer,bytes,sizeof(bytes));
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also showed the printf() statement you are using to show the resulting value of buffer.  The statement I would use:  printf("buffer = %d\n", *(int *)buffer);

Comment: [ To print sizeof(int), I would use: printf("sizeof(int) = %zu", sizeof(int));  ]